# Downloading images from a web server for the retina display iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, uiimage

I am downloading images from a webserver for display in a table view in my iOS application using the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
cell.imageView.image = myImage;
```

The image view is a 60x60 placeholder and 120x120 for the retina display. I am going to assume the user has an iPhone 4. However, if I size the image to 120x120 it does not correct the issue, it just becomes too big for the the imageview. If I size the image to 60x60, on the webserver that is, then the image fits fine but its a little fuzzy. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first agree that your `UIImageView` is 60x60 **points**, meaning 60x60 **pixels** for a standard display and 120x120 **pixels** for a retina display.

For a `UIImageView` at 60x60 points, the image should be 60x60 pixels at **scale 1.0** for a standard display and 120x120 pixels at **scale 2.0** for a retina display. This means that your `UIImage` should always have a `size` of 60x60 points, but should have a different `scale` depending on the display resolution.

When getting the image data from your server, you should first check the scale of the device's screen and then request the appropriate image size (in pixels), like so:

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1.0) {
    // Build URL for 60x60 pixels image
}
else {
    // Build URL for 120x120 pixels image   
}
```

Then you should put the image data in a `UIImage` of size `60x60` points, at the appropriate `scale`:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [imageData bytes], [imageData length]);
CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (cfdata);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imageDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                            scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale 
                                      orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
CFRelease (imageRef);
CFRelease (imageDataProvider);
CFRelease(cfdata);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your downloaded image have a size 2X from your UIImageView dimension size. It's look fine for retina display in iPhone4.

see also there: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/preparing-your-iphone-app-for-higher-resolutions/

Answer (score 0):

Images downloaded from the web are not formatted for Retina Display the same way images bundled with your app (using the "@2x" suffix) are.

You can get/set the scale of any UIView with the aptly named scale: and setScale: methods to help you better display content from the web if you know it's intended for Retina Display devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is as simple as it can be:

I would recommend always downloading the double density images from the server (as users with non retina display are very few) and setting in the imageview.

What you didn't do correctly is you didn't set the imageView to automatically fit the content.
You can do this either in IB by selecting the ImageView and setting the contentMode (mode) to scale to Fill, or by code:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't solve the problem? Are the images still too big to fit?